# max marks validation

Tags: javascript

i have some problem in javascript validation...
My requirement is user sholud enter value in text box less than 5
he sholud not allow to enter value which is more than 5
he can enter 4.25
3.10
he should not enter 5.1 how to restrict user not to do this..
what is code for this.on which event we sholud call it

Answer (score 2):

you can use `onBlur` event of textbox and then use

```
if(parseFloat(yourValue)<=limit)
```

Also you can use `isNaN(yourValue)` to check if it is a number.